# Falta traducir texto en los privilegios del sitio

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, privilegios

Estaba revisando la página de ayuda para privilegios, y todo el texto de la misma esta sin traducir, así como también toda la ayuda de cada privilegio esta sin traducir, a continuación coloco una captura de los mismos:

[image: Privilegios]
[image: Privilegios 2]

Comment: Tienes razón, faltan esas traducciones.  ¿Te gustaría ayudar con eso?

Comment: Hola @JuanM, si me gustaría ayudar, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Te acabo de mandar una invitación para acceder a Transifex, la plataforma que usamos para traducir las cadenas del sitio. ;)

Comment: Ok, ya la acepte :), ahí que hago? nunca he usado esa plataforma.

Comment: Te mande una invitación al chat en Gmail.  Te lo comento ahi.

Comment: Esto es muy raro. La lista de privilegios está traducida en Transifex desde hace mucho (de hecho recuerdo haberla traducido yo mismo antes de la beta pública). Investigaré.

Comment: Hola @Konamiman con el acceso que me dio JuanM a transifex busqué esas cadenas para traducir, pero no las encontré, me decia JuanM que se necesita editar la base de datos directamente para traducir esos textos.

Comment: @JuanM Podemos otros usuarios participar en Transifex para la traducción del sitio? Tenía entendido que el trabajo ya estaba todo hecho en ese lado y sólo quedaban las cadenas ninja!

Comment: @MiquelColl Claro que se puede, tenemos todavía bastante que traducir. Mándame un correo y te enviare una invitación al sistema.

Comment: Bueno, esto no va a ser tan fácil. En realidad no está traducido ninguno de los artículos del centro de ayuda que explican los privilegios, y es de estos artículos de donde se sacan los títulos para esta página. Hay mucho trabajo por delante.

Comment: @Konamiman estoy traduciendo esos textos como aporte para la comunidad en conjunto con JuanM, espero terminar lo más pronto posible, para que actualicen el sitio.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/998/quer%C3%A9is-ayudar-a-traducir-los-privilegios-hacedlo-aqu%C3%AD