# Traducir privilegios

Tags: soporte, bug, estado-completado, traducciones, privilegios

Recuerdo que ya estaba traducida, quiza algo paso, pero en este momento esta una versión en ingles

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

[image: Privilegio comentar]

Comment: Quizás, si estás (casi) seguro que estaba traducida, deberías reetiquetarla como [bug] y sacarle [discusión] y [soporte], orientándola a que revisen en el sistema si está traducida pero no se implementó.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/998/quer%C3%A9is-ayudar-a-traducir-los-privilegios-hacedlo-aqu%C3%AD/1008#1008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @alvaromontoro por su ayuda en la traducción de esta página que esta ahora en vivo.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 1):

Ya existe una pregunta aquí en meta acerca de eso [Falta traducir texto en los privilegios del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/750/falta-traducir-texto-en-los-privilegios-del-sitio), @Konamiman se encargo de revisar esto y dijo:

> En realidad no está traducido ninguno de los artículos del centro de
>   ayuda que explican los privilegios, y es de estos artículos de donde
>   se sacan los títulos para esta página (Página Principal de todos los privilegios).

Yo estoy traduciendo los privilegios para enviárselos a @JuanM y que  actualice el sitio una vez que toda la traducción este completa, aunque casi no he avanzado mucho por que ando un poco atareado en el trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora, la única traducción es esta (preguntas protegidas).

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions